# Calculating percent change of each subcategory through Teradata SQL, python, R, or Excel

Tags: python

```
CATEGORY  SUBCATEGORY   VALUES   %CHANGE?
   A           1          1
   A           2         10         900
   C           1          8
   C           2          16        100
   C           3          8        -50
```

So far, I only have category, subcategory, and values columns.
I want to add a column containing the percent change between each row's `VALUES` value and the one in the row above it. This should not be calculated when the row above belongs to a different category. Following the table above, `1` to `10` is a 900% increase, then the change from `10` to `8` is not calculated because the category switches from `A` to `C`, then `8` to `16` is a 100% increase, and so on.

I don't know whether to use R, Python, Teradata SQL, or Excel. How do I do this?

Comment: Excel is the easiest

Comment: @FirebladeDan how would you go about doing this in Excel??

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I looked up online and could not find exactly what I needed so that's why I'm posting here.

Comment: I don't understand how you're determining the values in the `%CHANGE?` column.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I'm using the (new-old)/old*100, a typical % change formula. For category A then,(10-1)/1*100=900.

Comment: So you just want to omit the calculation when a new category starts? That's as easy as not entering the equation in the corresponding cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the cell `D2` as shown below,  use the formula `=((C2/C1)*100-100)`, select the cells from D2 all the way down to the end of the column, and fill down (<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>). Delete it from the first row of each category.

Or, if you want it to determine that for you, use `=(IF(A2=A1,(C2/C1)*100-100,""))` instead and just fill down the whole column.

```
    A   B   C   D
1   A   1   1   
2   A   2   10  900
3   C   1   8   
4   C   2   16  100
5   C   3   8   -50
```

Comment: Your logic calculates % change for all categories, not for each subcategory.

Comment: Then you'll have to explain what you mean by that instead of just showing sample output.

Comment: Within category A, we calculate % change between subcategory 1 and 2. For category C, we calculate % change between each subcategory 1,2, and 3.

Comment: So don't add the equation to the first row of a category.

Comment: But the number of subcategories differ for each category. For instance, Category D might have 10 subcategories, C has only 3 subcategories, etc.

Comment: also, my dataset has 2000+ categories, so I can't just keep deleting % change of the first subcategories of each category manually.

Comment: Do they appear in order or out of order? Meaning, will everything in category A be grouped together?

Comment: @Jenny the most recent edit should do what you're looking for. Does it?

Comment: Thanks! That solved the problem.

Comment: @JennyBunge you can mark it as useful by clicking the checkmark below the score.

Answer (score 0):

Take Category, Subcategory, Values columns and paste them into an Excel Spreadsheet. Then create an equation in D2 box. Then drag down using corner of square.

```
A             B          C            D
CATEGORY  SUBCATEGORY   VALUES   % Change
  A           1          1         =*D2
  A           2         10         900
  C           1          8
  C           2          16        100
  C           3          8        -50
```

I have a feeling if you have never done this before you should have someone who is experienced show you. Or else you're gonna spend hours on this simple task.

Comment: Your logic calculates % change for all categories, not for each subcategory.

Comment: Your equation will declare that

Comment: I see what you're doing. You're making us think for you. No more help from me

Comment: This is a platform to ask questions after trying to solve the problem. I'm doing exactly that. So if you don't want to or cannot help, goodbye.

Comment: Exactly: after trying to solve the problem. All you did was present us with a task and then ask for a language recommendation. It's preferred that you explain what you've tried and the manner in which it didn't work.